# C Executed file doesn't work as expected on linux server

Tags: c, linux, debugging, ssh, terminal

I wrote a c file according to c99 standard and uploaded it to my collage's linux server by connecting to it through ssh and scp.
I debugged my file using the following command:

```
> gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG part1.c -o mtm_tot
```

and when I run the following command:

```
> ./mtm_tot< test1.in > tmpout
```

I write:

```
> cat tmpout
```

but nothing gets printed (the file is empty)
can someone help me understand why this happens?

I am working on macOS and using the terminal.
test1.in contents:

```
8
5 9 -1 4 20 256 -32 17 32
```

my c code if needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Error (-1)

int PowOf2(int num)
{
    if (num<=0) return Error;
    if (num==1) return 0;
    int counter=0;
    while (num>=2)
    {
        if (num%2!=0)
            return Error;
        counter++;
        num/=2;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    int inputs_num;
    printf("Enter size of input:\n");
    scanf("%d",&inputs_num);
    if (inputs_num<=0)
    {
        printf("Invalid size");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    int *saver=malloc(inputs_num* sizeof(int));
    if (saver==NULL)
        return 0;
    for (int i=0;i<inputs_num;i++)
    {
        int tmp=scanf("%d",&saver[i]);
        if (tmp==EOF)
        {
            printf("Invalid number");
            return 0;
        }

    }
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<inputs_num;i++)
    {
        int res=PowOf2(saver[i]);
        if (res!=-1)
        {
            sum+=res;
            printf("The number %d is a power of 2: %d = 2^%d\n",saver[i],saver[i],res);
        }
    }
    printf("Total exponent sum is %d",sum);
    free(saver);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just downloaded your code and test data and ran it under linux. It worked fine. I get three lines of output. So, this must be some `macOS` thing. I'd guess that the buffering on `stdout` holds all/most of the output data and you're getting some error (e.g. segfault) that prevents the stream data from being flushed to the file [at normal program exit]. Check `$?` after running the program. Run the program under `gdb` [compile with `-g`]. Run the program _without_ the output redirector. (e.g. _just_ `./mtm_tot < test1.in`)

Comment: Works for me on both Linux and MacOS. You should end the last printf with `\n`, but that won't make a big difference.

Comment: yes run right, with your inputs write "The number 4 is a power of 2: 4 = 2^2" then "The number 256 is a power of 2: 256 = 2^8" then "Total exponent sum is 10" with a new line for the two first lines

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (saver==NULL)
        return 0;`  1) The `if()`, when it finds an error, should inform the user of the problem.  Suggest calling: `perror( "malloc failed" );`  2) a returned value of 0 (typically) indicates success, but this code path is a failure path.  Suggest `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`